# Getting a substring in a mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

In my mysql table, one of the fields holds data of the nature:

```
{"gateway":"somevalue","location":"http://www.somesite.org/en/someresource","ip":"100.0.0.9"}
```

I need to extract the value of the location attribute alone from this field, which is

> http://www.somesite.org/en/someresource

in the this case. How do I write a query to achieve this?

Comment: That's a very good example (and motivation) of how you should NOT save information into the DB!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the fact that you better off not storing delimited values of any form (including JSON) in  the database, but rather normalize your data, you can leverage very handy [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function in the following way

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column_name, '"location":', -1), ",", 1)) location
  FROM table_name
 WHERE ...
```